# Log Results from a 'LinkedHashMap' to a New Line?

Tags: java

How do I print log results (stored in a 'LinkedHashMap') with linebreaks?

Currently the data is being capture and bundled all together instead of writing the each entry of the hashMap on a new line. My Code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> chromeConsoleOutputs = new ArrayList<String>();

public static StringBuilder returnFailedMethodsAndURLToNewLine() {
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> entries = failedTestsAndURL.entrySet().iterator();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = entries.next();
        result.append("<br>" + entry.getKey() + " |" + entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Maybe I have to alter something in this part of the code?

```
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = entries.next();
        result.append("<br>" + entry.getKey() + " |" + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Example of current log:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add an explicit newline character instead of the `<br>` tag, which is specific to HTML:

```
result.append("\n" + entry.getKey() + " |" + entry.getValue());
```

Common practice is to put newlines at the end of strings though.

```
result.append(entry.getKey() + " |" + entry.getValue() + "\n");
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i need to outputted / text log file to have a newline for each entry, \n dosnt work :/

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a:

```
private final static String LINE_SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator");
...

result.append("<br>" + entry.getKey() + " |" + entry.getValue());
result.append(LINE_SEP);
```

Notes here:

- You want to make sure to use that style of "newline" that really works for the OS your code runs on
- On the other hand, you do not want to make this System call during each loop; so you fetch that ONCE by making it a static constant

Answer (score 0):

Append "\n" in the string builder

```
result.append("<br>" + entry.getKey() + " |" + entry.getValue()).append("\n");
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i need to outputted / text log file to have a newline for each entry, \n dosnt work :/

Comment: Have you tried \r\n for windows and \n for unix/linux systems?